# AS3 Adobe Air Error Creating Files. The input line is too long

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing an mobile app using adobe air. Whem I amtrying to publish for iOS I am getting this error.
"Error Creating Files. The input line is too long."

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Its just because of I have added the files that have too long path. I copy the project to 'D' drive and the problem solved.